# Sequences and series natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

what is the sum of all three digit natural numbers that are multiples of 14, but not 21?
What is a quick way of doing sums like these, as i cannot rely on intuition during timed exams

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot rely on intuition"? In a well constructed timed exam you _have to_ rely on intuition to get everything right, because "well constructed" implies that it can distinguish between students who have developed a good intuition for the subject and those who just hammer formulas mindlessly.

Comment: Ok thats not exactly what i meant, what i meant was i cannot rely on innovation, and the more i have sorted put the better it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three-digit numbers that are divisible by 14 are
$$ 112, 126, \ldots, 994 $$
There are $\frac{994-112}{14}+1 = 64$ of them, so their sum is
$$ 64\times\frac{112+994}2 $$

Compute the sum of the numbers that are multiples of 42 (the least common multiple of 14 and 21) in the same way, and subtract them out.